# Crashed on Qt5WebEngineCore.dll without my code in the callstack

Tags: c++, qt

**What are the possible reasons for the program crash?
What are the possible solutions?**

Used the WebEngineView to load url.

No obvious errors were found in the logs

Exception Unhandled: Unhandled exception at 0x61664951 (Qt5WebEngineCore.dll) in DemoA.exe.5572.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0A4CC478.

call stack:

```
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::_Narrow_char_traits<char,int>::length(const char * const) Line 321 C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::string::assign(const char * const) Line 2984   C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::string::{ctor}(const char * const) Line 2339   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gl::GLSurface::ExtensionsContain(const char * c_extensions=0x0a4cc478, const char * name=0x63daf438) Line 270  C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gl::GLSurfaceQt::HasEGLExtension(const char * name=0x63daf438) Line 102    C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gl::GLContextEGL::Initialize(gl::GLSurface * compatible_surface, const gl::GLContextAttribs & attribs={...}) Line 104  C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!GLContextHelper::initializeContextOnBrowserThread(gl::GLContext * context=0x0a61dd30, gl::GLSurface * surface=0x0d940438, gl::GLContextAttribs attribs={...}) Line 104 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!GLContextHelper::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o=0x0a117c90, QMetaObject::Call _c=InvokeMetaMethod, int _id=0, void * * _a=0x00afc900) Line 81 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QMetaMethod::invoke(QObject * object=0x0a117c90, Qt::ConnectionType connectionType=DirectConnection, QGenericReturnArgument returnValue={...}, QGenericArgument val0={...}, QGenericArgument val1={...}, QGenericArgument val2={...}, QGenericArgument val3={...}, QGenericArgument val4={...}, QGenericArgument val5={...}, QGenericArgument val6={...}, QGenericArgument val7={...}, QGenericArgument val8={...}, QGenericArgument val9={...}) Line 2303  C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject * obj=0x0a117c90, const char * member=0x638d3fc4, Qt::ConnectionType type=DirectConnection, QGenericReturnArgument ret={...}, QGenericArgument val0={...}, QGenericArgument val1={...}, QGenericArgument val2={...}, QGenericArgument val3={...}, QGenericArgument val4={...}, QGenericArgument val5={...}, QGenericArgument val6={...}, QGenericArgument val7={...}, QGenericArgument val8={...}, QGenericArgument val9={...}) Line 1515 C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!GLContextHelper::initializeContext(gl::GLContext * context=0x0a61dd30, gl::GLSurface * surface=0x0d940438, gl::GLContextAttribs attribs={...}) Line 110 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gl::init::CreateGLContext(gl::GLShareGroup * share_group=0x0d93e518, gl::GLSurface * compatible_surface=0x0d940438, const gl::GLContextAttribs & attribs={...}) Line 200   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gpu::GLES2CommandBufferStub::Initialize(gpu::CommandBufferStub * share_command_buffer_stub, const GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig & init_params={...}, base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion shared_state_shm={...}) Line 312    C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gpu::GpuChannel::OnCreateCommandBuffer(const GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig & init_params={...}, int route_id=4, base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion shared_state_shm={...}, gpu::ContextResult * result=0x00afd354, gpu::Capabilities * capabilities=0x00afd174) Line 745    C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::DispatchToMethodImpl<gpu::GpuChannel *,void (__thiscall gpu::GpuChannel::*)(GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig const &,int,base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion,enum gpu::ContextResult *,gpu::Capabilities *),std::tuple<GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig,int,base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion>,std::tuple<enum gpu::ContextResult,gpu::Capabilities>,0,1,2,0,1>(gpu::GpuChannel * const & obj=0x1eee7438, void(gpu::GpuChannel::*)(const GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig &, int, base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion, gpu::ContextResult *, gpu::Capabilities *) method=0x61db23b5, std::tuple<GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig,int,base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion> && in={...}, std::tuple<enum gpu::ContextResult,gpu::Capabilities> * out=0x00afd174, std::integer_sequence<unsigned int,0,1,2> __formal={...}, std::integer_sequence<unsigned int,0,1> __formal={...}) Line 96   C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::DispatchToMethod(gpu::GpuChannel * const &) Line 105  C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!IPC::MessageT<GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer_Meta,std::tuple<GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig,int,base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion>,std::tuple<enum gpu::ContextResult,gpu::Capabilities>>::Dispatch<gpu::GpuChannel,gpu::GpuChannel,void,void (__thiscall gpu::GpuChannel::*)(GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig const &,int,base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion,enum gpu::ContextResult *,gpu::Capabilities *)>(const IPC::Message * msg=0x1e56f078, gpu::GpuChannel * obj=0x1eee7438, gpu::GpuChannel * sender=0x1eee7438, void * __formal=0x00000000, void(gpu::GpuChannel::*)(const GPUCreateCommandBufferConfig &, int, base::UnsafeSharedMemoryRegion, gpu::ContextResult *, gpu::Capabilities *) func=0x61db23b5) Line 205   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gpu::GpuChannel::OnControlMessageReceived(const IPC::Message & msg={...}) Line 567 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!gpu::GpuChannel::HandleMessageHelper(const IPC::Message & msg={...}) Line 620  C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::internal::FunctorTraits<void (__thiscall quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy::*)(storage::QuotaSettings const &),void>::Invoke<void (__thiscall quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy::*)(storage::QuotaSettings const &),base::WeakPtr<quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy> const &,storage::QuotaSettings const &>(void(quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy::*)(const storage::QuotaSettings &) method=0x61db214b, const base::WeakPtr<quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy> & receiver_ptr={...}, const storage::QuotaSettings & <args_0>={...}) Line 498   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::internal::InvokeHelper<1,void>::MakeItSo<void (__thiscall quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy::*const &)(storage::QuotaSettings const &),base::WeakPtr<quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy> const &,storage::QuotaSettings const &>(void(quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy::*)(const storage::QuotaSettings &) & functor=0x61db214b, const base::WeakPtr<quota_internals::QuotaInternalsProxy> & weak_ptr={...}, const storage::QuotaSettings & <args_0>={...}) Line 618    C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<void (__thiscall net::MDnsClientImpl::Core::*)(std::pair<std::string,unsigned short> const &),base::WeakPtr<net::MDnsClientImpl::Core>,std::pair<std::string,unsigned short>>,void __cdecl(void)>::RunImpl(void(net::MDnsClientImpl::Core::*)(const std::pair<std::string,unsigned short> &) && bound, std::tuple<base::WeakPtr<net::MDnsClientImpl::Core>,std::pair<std::string,unsigned short>> &&) Line 672    C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<void (__thiscall net::MDnsClientImpl::Core::*)(std::pair<std::string,unsigned short> const &),base::WeakPtr<net::MDnsClientImpl::Core>,std::pair<std::string,unsigned short>>,void __cdecl(void)>::RunOnce(base::internal::BindStateBase * base=0x1e56f060) Line 640 C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::OnceCallback<void __cdecl(void)>::Run() Line 98   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::TaskAnnotator::RunTask(const char * trace_event_name=0x63d2ac90, base::PendingTask * pending_task=0x08626be8) Line 142   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::DoWorkImpl(base::sequence_manager::LazyNow * continuation_lazy_now=0x00afd644, bool * ran_task=0x00afd667) Line 366 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::DoWork() Line 270   C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!QtWebEngineCore::MessagePumpForUIQt::handleScheduledWork() Line 202 C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!QtWebEngineCore::MessagePumpForUIQt::<lambda_b6c8be786af2f5959f95cee23156cb35>::operator()() Line 115   C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::invoke(QtWebEngineCore::MessagePumpForUIQt::<lambda_b6c8be786af2f5959f95cee23156cb35> &) Line 1596 C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::_Invoker_ret<void,1>::_Call(QtWebEngineCore::MessagePumpForUIQt::<lambda_b6c8be786af2f5959f95cee23156cb35> &) Line 1640    C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::_Func_impl_no_alloc<<lambda_b6c8be786af2f5959f95cee23156cb35>,void>::_Do_call() Line 903  C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!std::_Func_class<void>::operator()() Line 951   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5WebEngineCore.dll!QWebEngineMessagePumpScheduler::timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev=0x1e664660) Line 72    C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QObject::event(QEvent * e=0x1e664660) Line 1341 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Widgets.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver=0x0a135220, QEvent * e=0x1e664660) Line 3630   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Widgets.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver=0x0a135220, QEvent * e=0x1e664660) Line 3585 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject * receiver=0x0a135220, QEvent * event=0x1e664660) Line 1063   C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5Core.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject *) Line 1458 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver=0x00000000, int event_type, QThreadData * data=0x00214610) Line 1817   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::sendPostedEvents() Line 1081 C++ Symbols loaded.
qwindows.dll!QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::sendPostedEvents() Line 81 C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags={...}) Line 530   C++ Symbols loaded.
qwindows.dll!QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags={...}) Line 74  C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] Qt5Core.dll!QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) Line 139   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags={...}) Line 232   C++ Symbols loaded.
Qt5Core.dll!QCoreApplication::exec() Line 1372  C++ Symbols loaded.
DemoA.exe!main(int argc=12, char * * argv=0x03720f90) Line 164  C++ Symbols loaded.
DemoA.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal=0x00bc0000, HINSTANCE__ * __formal=0x00000000, char * __formal=0x00183cd8, int __formal=10) Line 98    C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] DemoA.exe!invoke_main() Line 102 C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
DemoA.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288 C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
```

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It is a large project, and can't reprodece it in my local environment.